# Como crear un archivo conjunto de varios archivos python en uno solo que se mantenga .py

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Quiero crear un juego en python usando pygame y que sea un archivo que esté Guardado en uno solo pero manteniendo el .py o .pyw en vez de usar un librería para volverlo .exe no existe alguna manera de igual que en otros juegos(minecraft las versiones del juego son .java y dentro tienen texturas y demás scripts) el archivo se mantenga .py y dentro ya se pueda abrir con win.rar y ver todos los archivos del juego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python puede ejecutar directamente un archivo `.zip` (aunque el convenio es cambiarle la extensión a `.pyz`, si bien nada te impide nombrarlo `.py` aunque se prestaría a confusión). El único requisito es que dentro del `.zip` haya un fichero llamado `__main__.py` por el que comenzaría la ejecución. Dentro del zip pueden haber más scripts (para ser importados desde `__main__.py`) e incluso paquetes y módulos de terceros, así como *assets* (imágenes, música, etc.) si bien el código tiene que estar preparado para cargar estos *assets* como si fueran parte de un paquete y no desde el sistema de archivos.

Una vez empaquetado todo en el .zip, podría ejecutarse así:

```
$ python archivo.pyz
```

Naturalmente el usuario tiene que tener python instalado (y posiblemente la misma versión de python que tú, si usaste características específicas de una versión). Y si el .zip contiene algunas bibliotecas binarias, sólo se podrá ejecutar en la plataforma para la que esas bibliotecas fueron compiladas (Windows, OSX, etc.)

Tienes más información sobre cómo crear este tipo de archivos, usarlos, e incluso convertirlos a .exe en la [documentación oficial de python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html) y sobre cómo acceder a recursos dentro de paquetes en la documentación del módulo estándar desde Python 3.7 [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources).

También puedes leer este [breve artículo](http://sheep.art.pl/Your%20Python%20Application%20as%20a%20Single%20File) con un ejemplo de cómo hacer esto específicamente para un juego PyGame, si bien menciona que para ejecutar el zip resultante es necesario tener instalado no sólo Python, sino también PyGame.